# How can I automatically mount a few remote folders at startup with SSHFS?

Tags: finder, ssh, mount, login, startup

I have two folders on a remote server, and I mount them locally on my Mac using MacFUSE and SSHFS, as described [here](https://susanqq.github.io/jekyll/pixyll/2017/09/05/remotefiles/) or [here](http://ssg.cs.ucdavis.edu/services/desktop-services/how-to-mount-remote-filesystems-over-ssh-on-a-mac):

```
sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions myuser@remote.server:/path/to/folder1 /Users/me/folder1
sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions myuser@remote.server:/path/to/folder2 /Users/me/folder2
```

The two mount commands work nicely, and I can access the folders. However, each time I shut down my Mac, the folders get unmounted, and I need to mount them again when I log in. This gets old very quickly. How can I have OSX mount the remote folders automatically each time I log in?

Comment: There are quite a few Q&A‘s on the site about how to automount drives, run scripts at startup etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nohillside searching the site for "automount drives" returns hits on how to automount external hard disks (not my case) or network drives (NAS) (again, not my case). Regarding "run scripts at startup", I don't know which script I should run. Why don't you point me to a specific answer, instead?

Comment: The process is similar in all cases, and somehow you need to have a way to run these sshfs commands. Some of the answers to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/in-os-x-10-6-how-do-you-mount-an-afp-share-at-boot-or-before-user-login might help.